# Annotation in pydev not showing correctly

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

On two installations of pydev on Windows (different computers) with Eclipse 4.4 the annotations of errors and warnings (e.g. also the output of pep8) are not shown correctly. Only the text in the file is marked with a red background but no icons are shown on the left and also no warnings and errors appear in the minimap.

screenshot with the problem: 
[image: screenshot with the problem]

correct version:
[image]
With a Linux installation everything is working (and also using a Windows installation on another computer)

Edit: This question is about the problem with the annotations not shown correctly and not with the results of the pep8 check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem starting form a fresh installation of Eclipse (Luna, Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Windows 64bit) and adding first PyDev and then other plugins until the problem reappears:

PyDev seems to be incompatible with "PTP Fortran Support" (installed from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna). Installing it causes the problem, uninstalling it solves it.

A diff of the Eclipse configuration before/after the problem appears can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jmozmoz/b6835a29b52487874df2

(PTP Fortran Support is e.g. also installed if Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers is installed. Unfortunately, it cannot removed separately.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) . The style guide does not allow multiple imports in one line

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to fix the problems with the annotations not shown correctly, i.e. only as background color and not icons and/or the marks in the minimap.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be problems with the "Overview Ruler Minimap" feature in PyDev. The minimap gives you a zoomed out impression of the document text in the right hand side "overview ruler" AKA "annotations ruler". The problem is, it doesn't work on some installations of Eclipse, causing a blank bar, or a minimap with no colour highlighting.

So if you're having problems with Eclipse's overview ruler / annotation ruler, and are using Pydev, try going back to simple coloured rectangles in the overview ruler:

**Preferences** > **PyDev** > **Editor** > **Overview Ruler Minimap**

Untick "Show minimap"

Restart Eclipse

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. But I think I found the problem (see my answer).